# Automatically accept getUserMedia with geckofx

Tags: c#, video-streaming, webrtc, geckofx

I want to build a C# application that receives a video stream created with webRTC. The idea is that I create a [AppRTC Room](https://apprtc.appspot.com/) using the browser on my smartphone(Firefox). The only thing my geckofx browser component should do is receive that stream.

When I create a AppRTC Room and I navigate my geckofx browser to that specific URL I can't see the stream my smartphone is producing. I think it has something to do with getUserMedia. Is there some way that I can automatically accept the stream my smartphone is making within my C# application?

You can find my C# code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace webRTC
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize("C:/Users/Stijn/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/webRTC/bin/Debug/xulrunner");
            geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("https://apprtc.appspot.com/r/752849252");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: at a guess: GeckoPreferences.User["media.navigator.permission.disabled"] = true;  ?

Comment: Thanks Tom! It worked fine :)